# Why is the following code not looping to print out the digits of an inputted number?

Tags: java, loops

I CAN ONLY USE BASIC VARIABLE TYPES (USED IN THE CODE), NO ARRAYS, ETC. 
I want this code to loop until it prints out the digits. For example, if the inputted number is 12345, I want it to Print

```
1 
2
3
4
5
```

However, it only prints

```
1
0
0
0
0
```

Any inputted number can only have 5 digits.

```java
int num = 0;
System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
num = linput.nextInt();
int n = 5; //should be 5 digits in inputted number;
int i = num;
for (n = 5; n >= 1; n--) {
    if (n > 0) {
        for (int p = n; p > 1; p--) {
            i = i / 10;
        }
        int samplei = I;
        i = i - (10 * (samplei / 10));
        if (i < 0) {
            i = (i * -1);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, it is very hard to read with all the extra space and incorrect indentation.  Also you should not need two loops for this, you just need 1 and use the `%` (modulo) operator.

Comment: If you would like people to read your code, you would be well advised to write it readably. In particular, with appropriate indentation. It should also be a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

1 - Using nested loop for every simple problem is very bad idea. Always try to go for non nested loop.

2 - In below code i am using an array list to store all digit and then printing it backward.

3 - Below code is a general code and will work for any length(number length).

```
    int num = 12345;
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int count = 0;
    while(num != 0) {
        al.add(num%10);
        num = num/10;
        count++;
    }
    for(int i = count-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your solution seems to be unnecessarily complicated?*

```
System.out.println( "Enter an integer: " );
int num = linput.nextInt();
("" + num).chars().forEach( c -> System.out.println( (char)c ) );
```

*Did I miss something?*

*…then You may not use streams neither?*

```
int num = linput.nextInt();    
String s = ("" + num);
for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
  System.err.println( s.charAt( i ) );
```

*…still not complicated enough?*

```
public void printTheDigits( int n ) {
  if( (n % 10) == 0 )
    return;
  printTheDigits( n / 10 );
  System.err.println( n % 10 );
}

int num = linput.nextInt();
printTheDigits( num );
```